# Getting high number of duplicate records with Apache Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

1. I have setup a Apache kafka cluster with three hosts.
2. I have created a topic with replication factor 3 and partition count 8.
3. I have divided my data equally among the 8 partitions.
4. I have 8 single threaded consumers and i am leaving kafka to do partition assignment to each consumer.
5. I am using enable auto commit as false and AckMode as RECORD.

**PROBLEM:**

When I stop and start the consumer. Duplicate message count is in hundreds. I am expecting a count not more than 8 since i have 8 consumers and AckMode is RECORD.

Please help!!!

This is my consumer config.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;


@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value(value = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    private String marketDataPersistConsumer;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Quote> marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Quote> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory(marketDataPersistConsumer));
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Quote> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(groupId), new StringDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer<>(Quote.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs(String groupId) {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListener messageListener() {
        return new MessageListener();
    }
}
```

and this is my Message Listner:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Header;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class MessageListener {


    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("debugLogger");

    private void persistQuote(Quote quote, int partition) {
        save(quote);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.market.topic.name}", containerFactory = "marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    public void marketDataPersistConsumerZero(@Payload Quote quote, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
        persistQuote(quote, partition);
        LOG.info("Consumed Quote:" + quote + " from partition:" + partition);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.market.topic.name}", containerFactory = "marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    public void marketDataPersistConsumerOne(@Payload Quote quote, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
        persistQuote(quote, partition);
        LOG.info("Consumed Quote:" + quote + " from partition:" + partition);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.market.topic.name}", containerFactory = "marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    public void marketDataPersistConsumerTwo(@Payload Quote quote, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
        persistQuote(quote, partition);
        LOG.info("Consumed Quote:" + quote + " from partition:" + partition);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.market.topic.name}", containerFactory = "marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    public void marketDataPersistConsumerThree(@Payload Quote quote, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
        persistQuote(quote, partition);
        LOG.info("Consumed Quote:" + quote + " from partition:" + partition);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.market.topic.name}", containerFactory = "marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    public void marketDataPersistConsumerFour(@Payload Quote quote, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
        persistQuote(quote, partition);
        LOG.info("Consumed Quote:" + quote + " from partition:" + partition);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.market.topic.name}", containerFactory = "marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    public void marketDataPersistConsumerFive(@Payload Quote quote, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
        persistQuote(quote, partition);
        LOG.info("Consumed Quote:" + quote + " from partition:" + partition);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.market.topic.name}", containerFactory = "marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    public void marketDataPersistConsumerSix(@Payload Quote quote, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
        persistQuote(quote, partition);
        LOG.info("Consumed Quote:" + quote + " from partition:" + partition);
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.market.topic.name}", containerFactory = "marketDataKafkaListenerContainerFactory", containerGroup = "${kafka.market.persist.consumergroup}")
    public void marketDataPersistConsumerSeven(@Payload Quote quote, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partition) {
        persistQuote(quote, partition);
        LOG.info("Consumed Quote:" + quote + " from partition:" + partition);
    }
}
```

**Kakfa Debug Logs**

> 11:32:26 DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit > list: {} 11:32:27 DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - > > Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15649,
>   metadata=''}, market-data-topic-dev3-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15408,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:27 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15648,
>   metadata=''}, market-data-topic-dev3-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15269,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:27 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15631,
>   metadata=''}, market-data-topic-dev3-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15515,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:27 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15657,
>   metadata=''}, market-data-topic-dev3-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15631,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:27 INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 -
>   partitions assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-0,
>   market-data-topic-dev3-1] 11:32:27 INFO 
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-2, market-data-topic-dev3-3] 11:32:27
>   INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-4, market-data-topic-dev3-5] 11:32:27
>   INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-6, market-data-topic-dev3-7] 11:32:27
>   DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:27 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list: {}
>   11:32:29 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70 - Processing
>   [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:15534 - Partition:6,
>   lastPrice=6, systemTime=null, tickTime=null, localTickTime=null,
>   localTickTimeEpoch=null, closePrice=15534, closeTime=null,
>   localCloseTime=null, localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null,
>   logMessage=null, tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15657,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=6,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15775,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15775,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15755,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15755,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15783,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15783,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15776,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15776,
>   metadata=''}} Aug 30, 2017 11:32:39 AM
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator
>   onJoinPrepare INFO: Revoking previously assigned partitions
>   [market-data-topic-dev3-2, market-data-topic-dev3-3] for group
>   market-data-persist-cg-dev3 2017-08-30 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:1063 - Stopping invoker
>   Aug 30, 2017 11:32:39 AM
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator
>   onJoinPrepare INFO: Revoking previously assigned partitions
>   [market-data-topic-dev3-4, market-data-topic-dev3-5] for group
>   market-data-persist-cg-dev3 2017-08-30 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:1063 - Stopping invoker
>   2017-08-30 11:32:39 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70 -
>   Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:16440 -
>   Partition:0, lastPrice=0, systemTime=null, tickTime=null,
>   localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null, closePrice=16440,
>   closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null, localCloseTimeEpoch=null,
>   messageState=null, logMessage=null, tradeVolume=null],
>   headers={kafka_offset=15777, kafka_receivedMessageKey=null,
>   kafka_receivedPartitionId=0,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] Aug 30, 2017 11:32:39 AM
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator
>   onJoinPrepare INFO: Revoking previously assigned partitions
>   [market-data-topic-dev3-6, market-data-topic-dev3-7] for group
>   market-data-persist-cg-dev3 2017-08-30 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:1063 - Stopping invoker
>   2017-08-30 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:1082 - Invoker stopped
>   2017-08-30 11:32:39 INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:242 -
>   partitions revoked:[market-data-topic-dev3-6,
>   market-data-topic-dev3-7] 2017-08-30 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15784,
>   metadata=''}} Aug 30, 2017 11:32:39 AM
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator
>   onJoinPrepare INFO: Revoking previously assigned partitions
>   [market-data-topic-dev3-0, market-data-topic-dev3-1] for group
>   market-data-persist-cg-dev3 2017-08-30 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15784,
>   metadata=''}} 2017-08-30 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:1063 - Stopping invoker
>   Aug 30, 2017 11:32:39 AM
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator
>   sendJoinGroupRequest INFO: (Re-)joining group
>   market-data-persist-cg-dev3 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:1082 - Invoker stopped
>   11:32:39 INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:242 - partitions
>   revoked:[market-data-topic-dev3-2, market-data-topic-dev3-3] 11:32:39
>   DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit
>   list: {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15777,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15777,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:1082 - Invoker stopped
>   11:32:39 INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:242 - partitions
>   revoked:[market-data-topic-dev3-4, market-data-topic-dev3-5] 11:32:39
>   DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit
>   list: {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15757,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15757,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:1082 - Invoker stopped
>   11:32:39 INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:242 - partitions
>   revoked:[market-data-topic-dev3-0, market-data-topic-dev3-1] 11:32:39
>   DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit
>   list: {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15778,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15778,
>   metadata=''}} Aug 30, 2017 11:32:39 AM
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator
>   onJoinComplete INFO: Setting newly assigned partitions
>   [market-data-topic-dev3-2] for group market-data-persist-cg-dev3 Aug
>   30, 2017 11:32:39 AM
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator
>   onJoinComplete INFO: Setting newly assigned partitions
>   [market-data-topic-dev3-6] for group market-data-persist-cg-dev3
>   11:32:39 DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 -
>   Committing: {market-data-topic-dev3-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15269,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15778,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15408,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15631,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15777,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15757,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15784,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:450 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15515,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:39 INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 -
>   partitions assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-1] 11:32:39 INFO 
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-0] 11:32:39 INFO 
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-3] 11:32:39 INFO 
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-7] 11:32:39 INFO 
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-4] 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list: {}
>   11:32:39 INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-6] 11:32:39 INFO 
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-2] 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list: {}
>   11:32:39 DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 -
>   Received: 0 records 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list: {}
>   11:32:39 INFO  KafkaMessageListenerContainer:247 - partitions
>   assigned:[market-data-topic-dev3-5] 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70 - Processing [GenericMessage
>   [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:16448 - Partition:0, lastPrice=0,
>   systemTime=null, tickTime=null, localTickTime=null,
>   localTickTimeEpoch=null, closePrice=16448, closeTime=null,
>   localCloseTime=null, localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null,
>   logMessage=null, tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15778,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list: {}
>   11:32:39 DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 -
>   Received: 500 records 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70 - Processing [GenericMessage
>   [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:16324 - Partition:4, lastPrice=4,
>   systemTime=null, tickTime=null, localTickTime=null,
>   localTickTimeEpoch=null, closePrice=16324, closeTime=null,
>   localCloseTime=null, localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null,
>   logMessage=null, tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15757,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=4,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:39 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list: {}
>   11:32:49 DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 -
>   Commit list: {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15909,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15909,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70
>       - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:17474 - Partition:2, lastPrice=2, systemTime=null,
>   tickTime=null, localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null,
>   closePrice=17474, closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null,
>   localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null, logMessage=null,
>   tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15907,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=2,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15883,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15883,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15907,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15907,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15914,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15914,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15645,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15645,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70
>       - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:17598 - Partition:6, lastPrice=6, systemTime=null,
>   tickTime=null, localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null,
>   closePrice=17598, closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null,
>   localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null, logMessage=null,
>   tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15915,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=6,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15395,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15395,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15536,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15536,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:49 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70
>       - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:17482 - Partition:2, lastPrice=2, systemTime=null,
>   tickTime=null, localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null,
>   closePrice=17482, closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null,
>   localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null, logMess 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15774,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15774,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70
>       - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:13489 - Partition:1, lastPrice=1, systemTime=null,
>   tickTime=null, localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null,
>   closePrice=13489, closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null,
>   localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null, logMessage=null,
>   tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15408,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=1,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15922,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15922,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15896,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15896,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15920,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15920,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15928,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15928,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70
>       - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:17608 - Partition:0, lastPrice=0, systemTime=null,
>   tickTime=null, localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null,
>   closePrice=17608, closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null,
>   localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null, logMessage=null,
>   tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15923,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15659,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70
>       - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:14659 - Partition:3, lastPrice=3, systemTime=null,
>   tickTime=null, localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null,
>   closePrice=14659, closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null,
>   localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null, logMessage=null,
>   tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15550,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=3,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15659,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70
>       - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:15557 - Partition:5, lastPrice=5, systemTime=null,
>   tickTime=null, localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null,
>   closePrice=15557, closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null,
>   localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null, logMessage=null,
>   tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15660,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=5,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:560 - Received: 0
>   records 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15550,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15550,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:961 - Commit list:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15408,
>   metadata=''}} 11:32:50 DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter:70
>       - Processing [GenericMessage [payload=Quote [ricCode=Sequence:16559 - Partition:7, lastPrice=7, systemTime=null,
>   tickTime=null, localTickTime=null, localTickTimeEpoch=null,
>   closePrice=16559, closeTime=null, localCloseTime=null,
>   localCloseTimeEpoch=null, messageState=null, logMessage=null,
>   tradeVolume=null], headers={kafka_offset=15781,
>   kafka_receivedMessageKey=null, kafka_receivedPartitionId=7,
>   kafka_receivedTopic=market-data-topic-dev3}]] 11:32:50 DEBUG
>   KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer:965 - Committing:
>   {market-data-topic-dev3-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15408,
>   metadata=''}}

Comment: Your configuration is a little unusual; you really only need one `@KafkaListener` instead of 8 identical ones; just set the container factory's `concurrency` to 8. That said, it's logically the same. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging to watch the commits occur.

Comment: Hi @Garry Russell -  I tried doing the change but still the same results.
How do i turn on DEBUG log for Kafka? Any pointers?

Comment: Configure your logging subsystem (log4j, logback etc) to enable DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.kafka` and `org.apache.kafka` categories.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have added kafka debug logs. It seems like commit is happening at some interval and not after each record that is sent to listener?

Comment: Yes; the commits have to happen on the consumer thread; you can reduce the `pollTimeout` to make them happen more often; the default is 1000ms. In 1.3, we have a much simpler threading model which will allow the commits to happen more timely.

Comment: @GaryRussell I am using AckMode as RECORD then why is it happening at intervals and not each record received by listener?


**The MessageListener
is called for each record; the following describes the action taken by the container for each AckMode :
• RECORD - commit the offset when the listener returns after processing the record.**


I am trying to figure out a commit strategy with minimum duplicates.

Comment: The consumer is not thread safe. We have to wait until the poll returns. It will be better in 1.3 thanks to KIP-62.

Comment: I just have access to max release version **1.2.2.RELEASE**.

**What is the best strategy or configuration i can use to get minimum duplicates ?**

Comment: Right; 1.3 will be released next month; there's a milestone available (1.3.0.M2) but it doesn't yet have the improved logic. You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/405). In the meantime, reducing the poll timeout should help.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell. If i move from spring-kafka to apache kafka direct API and do the **consumer.commitSync();** manually after each record. Will i get rid of Duplicates ?

[https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html]

Comment: You will reduce, but not eliminate, the possibility of duplicates; as I said, 1.3 will support what you need.

Comment: One last thing @GaryRussell, do you know the exact dates for 1.3 RELEASE ?